# Python スクリプト実行時にエラー: "NameError: name 'Color' isn't defined"

Tags: python, python3

私は「これからのロボットプログラミング入門」という本を読み進めています。EV3 MIND STORMをPythonでプログラミングしようというやつです。専門用語が多くなってしまうので、実際にこの教材を進められた方にのみわかる質問文となっていますのでご了承ください。

本題です。P.68の「ステータスライトを光らせる」についてです。Pythonでの記述方法がその隣に載っているのですが、それを実行するとエラーが出ます。

```
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython
from common import *

brick.light(Color.ORANGE)
wait(2000)
```

を実行すると

```
NameError: name 'Color' isn't defined
```

となります。common.pyにも間違いを何度も探しました。こちらです。

```
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython
from pybricks import ev3brick as brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import Motor, InfraredSensor, UltrasonicSensor,
from pybricks.parameters import Port, ImageFile, SoundFile
from pybricks.tools import wait, StopWatch
from pybricks.robotics import DriveBase
```

ネットで調べても該当例がなかったので質問させていただきました。お心当たりのある方いらっしゃっいましたら是非ご回答をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その本のことは何も知らないですが、`Color` を足すとよさそうです。

**修正前:**

```
from pybricks.parameters import Port, ImageFile, SoundFile
```

**修正後:**

```
from pybricks.parameters import Port, ImageFile, SoundFile, Color
```

参考資料: https://pybricks.github.io/ev3-micropython/examples/color_sorter.html